# vite get env vars when targeting es6

Tags: vite

Vite's docs say

> Vite exposes env variables on the special import.meta.env object

But, when targeting es6 (i.e. `viteConfig.esbuild.target === "es6"`), Vite emits warnings on each access of import.meta, saying `import.meta is not available in the configured environment`. The files with `import.meta.env.foo` are .ts files that will run on the client.

In this case, should they be accessed via `process.env`, and does Vite guarantee they'll be there? Or instead should this be handled with a string-replacing rollup plugin?

Comment: Accessing from where? Application code or Vite config itself ?

Comment: from within application code -- javascript running on a client. I'll clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case. If you change the target to `esnext` it should work according to some GitHub issues: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10167

However, if you really need to target `es6`, for example, if you are building for something to be run in a browser IIFE, you can take this approach which worked for me:

```js
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    // Manually put anything VITE_ related on process.env,
    // because we cannot use import.meta.env a build that needs
    // to be compatible with browsers / iife target.
    //
    ...Object.keys(process.env)
      .filter((k) => k.startsWith('VITE_'))
      .reduce((acc, k) => ({ ...acc, [`process.env.${k}`]: JSON.stringify(process.env[k]) }), {}),
  },
})
```

Then, you can access the variables using `process.env`:

```js
var myVar = process.env.VITE_XXXXXXXXX
```